# Spring SAML sample app fails with Ping Federation

Tags: spring, ping, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Hy Guys,

I have been trying to integrate spring sample app, downloaded from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml, with Ping Federate. I have used this sample app to integrate with so many other IDPs and it worked fine without any hassles. But Ping Federate seems to be bit complicated. This is what I did so far.

1. Create connection in Ping using my SP meta data.
2. Export Ping meta data
3. Configure it in my SP (securityContext.xml)
4. Start the server

I get various errors at various scenarios. The one which I am currently testing, 
has following error on server restart,

**org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP**

On investigating the logs, I see the root cause to be

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.opensaml.saml2.common.SAML2Helper.getEarliestExpiration(SAML2Helper.java:112)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.processCachedMetadata(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:328)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:258)**

However, everything works fine if I disable **metadataTrustCheck** in *securityContext.xml* using property

**< property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>**

Can some one please help? I have been trying to solve this past one week. Unfortunately there is no good enough documentation from Ping for the version (latest) I am using.

**Update:**

Application works fine if,

1. Metadata trust check is disabled at SP and PF metadata is signed
2. Metadata trust check is enabled at SP and PF metadata is unsigned

However, I am getting above **NullPointerException** if

3. Metadata trust check is enabled at SP and PF metadata is signed

Comment: Just a guess -- Are you signing the connection meta-data you are exporting from PF? If so, chances are it's being signed with a self-signed cert which your sample app doesn't trust. Try re-exporting from PF as un-signed meta-data.

Comment: Yes. You got it right. I am signing the metadata with self signed cert. Let me try without signing enabling **metadataTrustCheck**.

Comment: Great. It works.

How can I make it work with signed meta data?

Comment: You need to add the public key of the meta-data signing cert to your local application trusted CA store.

Comment: @Ian, I did that. It isn't working. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I've also tried importing the certificate in my keystore but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, we had exactly the same `NullPointerException` with IDP metadata (using opensaml 2.6.4). As written above, setting `metadataTrustCheck="false"` on the `ExtendedMetadataDelegate` did solve the problem, but was not the desired solution.
Alternatively, one could have removed the `<Signature>` block from the metadata, which is equally as bad.

**Solution:**
Besides adding the (self-signed) certificate, it was necessary to add the **next** certificate in the chain to the keystore as well.

**For the interested reader:**
Despite this error, the application continued to start and claimed "*Reloading metadata was finished*".
However, there's a `TimerTask`, which regularly checks whether metadata providers where changed i.e., if a new one was registered. Supposedly, this happens only at startup time.
Regardless, every 10 seconds (by default), a refresh is triggered internally, which leads to calculation of the expiration time. If the metadata is not loaded for any reason e.g., because of a validation error, then this leads to the mentioned `NullPointerException` in `getEarliestExpiration()`.
If you're using a file-based `MetadataProvider` you might want customize the `CachingMetadataManager` and set `refreshCheckInterval="-1"` to disable this `TimerTask`.

PS: Maybe there are other reasons like a typo in the `entityID`, an overdue `validUntil`, expired certificates,... you name it. Anything, which causes the metadata not to be loaded will likely result in this issue. Another indicator is the following exception:

`Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Metadata for issuer <ENTITY_ID> wasn't found`